# How to fix pattern matching recursive call for tuples OCAML?

Tags: ocaml

I'm coding a helper function for encodeHelper but cannot seem to get the pattern matching to work in the recursive call. Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Please look at the code and error message in UTOP

```
let rec encodeHelper (l : 'a list) (curr : ('a * int) list) (currElement : ('a * int) option) =
   match l, currElement with 
   | [], None -> curr
   | [], Some(k) as currElement -> curr @[(fst k, snd k)]
   | hd1::tl, None -> encodeHelper tl curr (k, 1)
   | hd::tl, Some(k) -> 
      let element_ = fst k and
      amount = snd k in
      if element_ = hd
         then encodeHelper tl curr (element_, amount+1)
      else
         encodeHelper tl (curr @ [(element_, amount)]) (hd, 1)
```

The error message is that `(k,1)` in the recursive call on the 5th line is `This expression has type 'b * 'c but an expression was expected of type ('a * int) option`

Let me know if you have tips / ways to fix this!

Comment: Looking at this pattern-match: `[], Some(k) as currElement -> curr @[(fst k, snd k)]` I wonder why you've shadowed the name `currElement` when you never use it.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on input and expected output for `encodeHelper`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is telling you that this expression is wrong:

```
encodeHelper tl curr (k, 1)
```

Indeed, the third argument of `encodeHelper` is specified to be of type `('a * int) option` and the expression `(k, 1)` can't possiblly be of this type. An option type is `None` or `Some x`.

Possibly it will work better if you replace `(k, 1)` with `(Some (k, 1))`. However I don't see a definition of `k` in this branch of the match.